# ¿Cómo filtro mis datos cada hora en un data frame en python?

Tags: python, dataframe, filtro

Buen día. Tengo la siguiente data tomada con intervalos de media hora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo filtrar los datos registrados cada hora, por ejemplo que un data frame solo tenga los datos a las 20:00:00, 21:00:00, 22:00:00, 23:00:00...

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?